# using jquery mobile with jquery

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

Hi all I have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but for some reason in Chrome and on any android it just crashes the page and at the bottom I just get a "Loading" message

does anyone know why?

thanks

Comment: if that's all of your code, then maybe it is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Don't use jQuery 2.0 with jQuery mobile 1.3.1

jQuery Mobile is locked to a certain jQuery version range. Use only jQuery 1.7 up to 1.9.X

And you have several errors in your live example.

CSS should be initialized before js files and your HTML tag was missing. Also DIV containing the page must have **`data-role="page"`** attribute.

### EDIT :

Your final code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Packer Forbes Communications</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pageHead" data-role="page">
<div id="logo"><img src="images/packerForbesLogo.jpg" width="226" height="106" alt="Packer Forbes" /></div>
  <div id="socMedia"><a href="http://www.pmlive.com/pmhub/healthcare_public_relations/packer_forbes_communications" target="_blank"><img src="/images/socIconPM.jpg" width="35" height="40" alt="PMLive" /></a><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/packer-forbes-communications?trk=top_nav_home" target="_blank"><img src="/images/socIconIN.jpg" width="35" height="40" alt="LinkedIn" /></a><a href="https://twitter.com/PackerForbes" target="_blank"><img src="/images/socIconTW.jpg" width="35" height="40" alt="Twitter" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4D83CC0DD394EF97&feature=view_all" target=_"blank"><img src="/images/socIconYT.jpg" width="35" height="40" alt="YouTube" /></a></div>

  <div id="mainNav" role="navigation"> 
  <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation" class="mobileonly">Show navigation</a> 
  <a href="#" title="Hide navigation" class="mobileonly">Hide navigation</a>
    <ul id="nav" class="clearfix">
      <li><a href="/index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/what-we-do/index.html">What We Do</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/what-we-do/market-access/index.html">Market Access</a></li>
            <li class="navIndent"><a href="/what-we-do/market-access/case-studies.html">Case Studies</a></li>
            <li><a href="/what-we-do/pr/index.html">Public Relations</a></li>
            <li class="navIndent"><a href="/what-we-do/pr/case-studies.html">Case Studies</a></li>
            <li><a href="/what-we-do/medical-education/index.html">Medical Education</a></li>
            <li class="navIndent"><a href="/what-we-do/medical-education/case-studies.html">Case Studies</a></li>
            <li><a href="/what-we-do/digital/index.html">Digital</a></li>
            <li class="navIndent"><a href="/what-we-do/digital/case-studies.html">Case Studies</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/about-us/index.html">About Us</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/about-us/awards.html">Awards</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about-us/the-team.html">The Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about-us/life-at-packer-forbes.html">Life at Packer Forbes</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about-us/our-values.html">Our Values</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/clients/index.html">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="/news/index.html">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="/careers/index.html">Careers</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/careers/training.html">Training</a></li>
          <li><a href="/careers/internships.html">Internships</a></li>
          <li><a href="/careers/benefits.html">Benefits</a></li>
          <li><a href="/careers/current-vacancies.html">Current Vacancies</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://downloads.packerforbes.com" target="_blank">Download Centre</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="mainBanner"><a href="/news/index.html"><img src="images/twentyBanner.gif" alt="We Are Twenty!" width="400" height="80" border="0" class="homeBanner" /></a></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="mainBody">
    <div id="contentWrapper">
  <p class="brandStrip">&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="mainColumn">
            <!--<h1>Who We Are</h1>-->
            <h2>What We Do</h2>
            <div id="marketAccess"> <a href="/what-we-do/market-access/index.html"><img src="images/marketAccess.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="Market Access" /></a>
            <h3><a href="/what-we-do/market-access/index.html">Market Access</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div id="communications"> <a href="/what-we-do/pr/index.html"><img src="images/communications.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="Communications" /></a>
              <h3><a href="/what-we-do/pr/index.html">Public Relations</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div id="medicalEducation"> <a href="/what-we-do/medical-education/index.html"><img src="images/medicalEducation.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="Medical Education" /></a>
            <h3><a href="/what-we-do/medical-education/index.html">Medical Education</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div id="digital"><a href="/what-we-do/digital/index.html"><img src="images/digital.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="Digital" /></a>
              <h3><a href="/what-we-do/digital/index.html">Digital</a></h3>
            </div>
            <p class="firstParaHome">Packer Forbes is an award-winning independent healthcare communications consultancy, specialising in medical communications.  Our integrated approach ensures that our clients benefit from a compelling fusion of bespoke market access, public relations, medical education and digital communications approaches, all built on insight developed from years of experience.</p>
            <p class="dividerLong"><span class="dividerLongMore"><a href="/what-we-do/index.html">Find Out More»</a></span></p>
            <p class="mobileindexorgslogos">
                <a href="http://www.hca-uk.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logoHCA.jpg" width="102" height="109" alt="HCA" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.emig.org.uk/" target="_blank" class="mobileindexorgslogosemig"><img src="images/logoEMIG.jpg" width="102" height="109" alt="EMIG" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.investorsinpeople.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logoIIP.jpg" width="121" height="109" alt="IIP" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.abpi.org.uk/about-us/membership/Pages/general-affiliate-list.aspx#p" target="_blank"><img src="images/abpi_new.jpg" width="102" height="109" alt="IIP" /></a>
                <div class="mobileclear"></div>
            </p>

      </div>
        <div id="sideColumn"></div>
        <p class="brandStrip">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pageFoot">
    <ul>
        <li>1.09 Harbour Yard, Chelsea Harbour, London, SW10 0XD</li>
        <li>t: +44 (0)20 7036 8550</li>
        <li>f: +44 (0)20 7036 8569</li>
        <li><a href="mailto:healthmail@packerforbes.com">e: healthmail@packerforbes.com</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/cookie-policy.html">cookie policy</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Registered office: Packer Forbes Communications Ltd, 1.09 Harbour Yard, Chelsea Harbour, SW10 0XD Registered number: 3753460  </p>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ive downloading and im using 1.8.2 but its still doing the same, have you any more ideas?

Comment: You have forgor to initialize jQuery Mobile css. Only then your test page will be correct. I have looked at your demo page.

Comment: Use this version of js and css: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/04/10/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-3-1/ don't try to mix 1.3.0 beta js and 1.3.1. css.

Comment: it seems that i need to use use jquery.css for jquery.mobile to work. but if I use jquery.css it messes everything else up but thanks anyway

Comment: Tell me what do you need jQuery Mobile for?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQM 1.3.1, you can use this 2 script files.

jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1 http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/js/jquery.js

jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/js/jquery.mobile.min.js

## `Loading` message error

If you want to hide this message, try to use this as soon as on load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui-loader').hide();
});
```

Comment: ive just changed my jquery files for the ones you suggested and its still the same. Ive created a demo page to see here http://packerforbes.anytimeafter9.co.uk/delete.html

Comment: so, you don't want the JQM style? Try to remove [reset.css] file and see? Loading message error is because of JQM added a hidden loading message and it will be shown according to some event.

Comment: Ha yes that does get rid of the error message but jquery is still disable for the rest of the page. http://packerforbes.anytimeafter9.co.uk/delete.html

Comment: Ive deleted all css includes and all other javascript includes now so I just have the two javascript includes and I'm still getting this "Loading" error

Comment: Now add this JQM css, http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.min.css

Comment: I've added that and it seems to have got rid of the loading error

Comment: Yes, also check JQM demos http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/pages/

Comment: is jquery mobile reliant jquery.mobile.css??

Comment: Yes, JQM js will change/update your basic html markup to its markup and it will use JQM css. I think what you are doing now is not a JQM mobile site, just a responsive site.

Comment: it seems that if i include "jquery.mobile.min.css" it works but then it screws the rest of my css up. I only wanted to to the the orientation part of it. Is there another way of detecting when orientation changes without jquery.mobile does anyone know

Comment: Yes, because JQM use single page with multiple page section, btw why you want to include JQM js to your site?? What function you wanna use?

Comment: im trying to use the event.orientation